# Haskell map list of tuples to list of tuples

Tags: list, haskell, dictionary, tuples

I'm trying to map a list of tuples into a different list of tuples with no luck.

Example input:

```
a = [("eo","th"),("or","he")]
```

Example output:

```
[('e','t'),('o','h'),('o','h'),('r','e')]
```

I have tried:

```
map (\(a,b) -> (a!!0,b!!0):(a!!1,b!!1):[]) a
```

but it produces:

```
[[('e','t'),('o','h')],[('o','h'),('r','e')]]
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `concat` on your result or use `concatMap` instead of `map`. After all, you return lists in your map and therefore get a list of lists.

---

Let's give your function a name and a type:

```
magic :: [([Char], [Char])] -> [(Char, Char)]
```

Now, we can think of this as a two-step process: from every pair in the original list we're going to get a list:

```
magicPair :: ([Char], [Char]) -> [(Char, Char)]
magicPair (a,b) = zip a b
```

Now we need to map `magicPair` over all elements in your original list and concatenate the result:

```
magic xs = concat (map magicPair xs)
```

The combination `concat . map f` is so common that there is a function called `concatMap` for this:

```
magic xs = concatMap magicPair xs
```

And using a function `f` on a pair instead of two arguments is also common, so `magicPair = uncurry zip`:

```
magic xs = concatMap (uncurry zip) xs
```

We can now remove `xs` on both sides to end up with the final variant of `magic`:

```
magic = concatMap (uncurry zip)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick way to give you the output

```
simplify = (>>= uncurry zip)
```

Comment: Which is completely obfuscated for any language beginner.

Comment: @Zeta - .... and which will entice them into wanting to learn more about how cool Haskell is.